# Monitoring performance of opensips presence server

Tags: opensips

I have to do some performance testing of the opensips server but I am not able to start.

For generating traffic I'll be using SIPP. I am not able to find about how to monitor the performance of opensips in real time.

I know there is tool- **opensipsctl** but I am not able to run it. It gives below error:

```
ERROR: Error opening OpenSIPS's FIFO /tmp/opensips_fifo
ERROR: Make sure you have the line 'modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")' in your config
ERROR: and also have loaded the mi_fifo module.
```

And this is from the config file:

```
#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)
```

I am trying to find the cause from forums.

I also tried to install nagios but not able to add service for opensips, basically unable to understand how to do.

I have another doubt regarding the memory management. As I understand, opensips uses pre-configured amount of memory no matter how much memory is available. I guess which means I won't be able to find the actual memory consumption. I even tested some load where I just saw spikes on CPU usage and no spike on memory usage. Please correct if I understood wrong.

I really need some help to understand how to go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To resolve your mod_fifo related error, please confirm if /tmp/mod_fifo file is exists or not. And if its not there do this

```
touch /tmp/mod_fifo
chmod 777 /tmp/mod_fifo
/etc/init.d/opensips restart
```

And regarding your memory doubt,
Private memory is the memory used by one process, while shared memory is 
memory accessible by all processes (it is an IPC method, see 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).

The private memory is used 
for temporary storages required for certain processing by a process, 
while the shared memory is used to store data that must be accessible by 
all processes. Opensips init script has that memory related prameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately my linux machine sort of crashed, I can just have a console login. However, I checked and noticed that the file you mentioned does not exist.
Once I have a new setup ready I'll test this and update.

Comment: To test all this stuff console login is enough, anyways let me know once your system is ready.

Comment: I understand but opensips is not starting. BTW a side question, do you have any experience on performance testing of opensips? I am kind of struggling to find proper ways.

Comment: No, i've never done performance testing with Opensips but I guess you should take a look to this http://www.opensips.org/About/PerformanceTests

Comment: Thanks. I had checked that but I have to have a my own performance results and I am just working with presence server.

Comment: Followed the steps by @juned but problem persists of not finding /tmp/opensips_fifo . Any other suggestions ?